# Custom User model fields (AbstractUser) not showing in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have extended User model for django, using AbstractUser method. The problem is, my custom fields do not show in django admin panel.

My models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_bot_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Thanks

Comment: please specify django version

Comment: have you done the migrations?
`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: @aashu django 2.0, and yes, i did python manage.py makemigrations and after that migrate

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to override `UserAdmin` as well, if you want to see your custom fields. There is an [example here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) in the documentation.

You have to create the form for creating (and also changing) user data and override `UserAdmin`. Form for creating user would be:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

You override `UserAdmin` with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_bot_flag', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
```

and then you register:

```
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I pretty much copy/pasted this from documentation and deleted some code to make it shorter. Go to the documentation to see the full example, including example code for changing user data.

Comment: Thank You, that helped me to find solution, my was easier - I had to add this to my admin.py: class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    filter_horizontal = ('user_permissions', 'groups',)

Answer (score 32):

If all you want to do is add new fields to the standard edit form (not creation), there's a simpler solution than the one presented above.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .models import User


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,  # original form fieldsets, expanded
        (                      # new fieldset added on to the bottom
            'Custom Field Heading',  # group heading of your choice; set to None for a blank space instead of a header
            {
                'fields': (
                    'is_bot_flag',
                ),
            },
        ),
    )


admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

This takes the base fieldsets, expands them, and adds the new one to the bottom of the form. You can also use the new `CustomUserAdmin` class to alter other properties of the model admin, like `list_display`, `list_filter`, or `filter_horizontal`. The same expand-append method applies.

Answer (score 10):

The quickest way to show your extra fields in the Django Admin panel for an AbstractUser model is to unpack the UserAdmin.fieldsets tuple to a list in your admin.py, then edit to insert your field/s in the relevant section and repack as a tuple (see below).
Add this code in `admin.py` of your Django app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

fields = list(UserAdmin.fieldsets)
fields[0] = (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password', 'is_bot_flag')})
UserAdmin.fieldsets = tuple(fields)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

**Note**:
list(UserAdmin.fieldsets) gives the following list:

```
[  (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}), 
   ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}), 
   ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 
'user_permissions')}), 
   ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')})
]
```

These fields are by default in Django user models, and here we are modifying the first index of the list to add our custom fields.

Answer (score 5):

### Try this...

---

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


# Create your models here.
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

**settings.py** : Add below line of code in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomUser
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


# Register your models here.
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
        (
            'Other Personal info',
            {
                'fields': (
                    'phone_number',
                )
            }
        )
    )


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**After all are done then run below command in terminal**

> python manage.py makemigrations
>
> python manage.py migrate
>
> python manage.py runserver