# User custom extend AbstractUser does not appear in 'Authentication' admin panel

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I know this problem is common on stack, and I've tried numerous answers [Like this one, and more alike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011275/custom-user-model-fields-abstractuser-not-showing-in-django-admin).

So my goal is to extend User to add some custom fields.

In models.py I have added the following

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
   bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
   birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self): # __str__ for Python 3, __unicode__ for Python 2
      return self.name

   class Meta:
      app_label = 'app_name'
```

In admin.py I have added the following:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
   model = MyUser
   filter_horizontal = ('user_permissions', 'groups',)

admin.site.register(MyUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

In settings.py I have the following:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.MyUser'
```

In urls.py:

```
admin.autodiscover()
```

To be noted that I have deleted all my migrations and regenerated them after these changes

app_name is in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

I have also tried to add in form.py custom Creation and Change form like follows, without success:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta(UserCreationForm):
       model = MyUser
       fields = '__all__'
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
   class Meta:
       model = MyUser
       fields = '__all__'
```

To be noted that in my database, the user schema is updated with the new field !
[image: Database screenshot]

But the problem is that it does not appear in the admin pannel section
[image: admin pannel screenshot]

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Did you add `app_name` to `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Yes :) I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) recommend using a `OneToOne` relation to the default `User` model to extend it. Try following the docs and see if it works.
You have created a new user model from scratch ([click](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)), but seem to have left out a lot of required stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
Indeed, the One to one method works, but it appears in the admin pannel in its own section. So I would like to extend the native user object.
The other link you posted is to extend the AbstractBaseUser, but it's a bit overkill, as I just want to add some fields. So the AbstractUser extension is best fitted.

Comment: Have you implemented the admin changes like they are described in the docs? They unregister the default UserAdmin and replace it with a new one with the new fields as an inline. It should still show up under the `auth` app in the index, above `Groups`.